# Sql Query to Drill down to a table to minimum level as per RoleID and Hierarchy Structure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a application where users are entering their time efforts .We have two tables, `Production` table for entering all production tasks and `NonProduction` for entering all non production related tasks in the application.We also have a `UserInfo` table where all the user information is stored like his eCode, Name, Designation,RoleID,ImmediateSupervisor ECode to whom the user is reporting etc. 
We are trying to make a sql query in such manner so that any users whose roleid is greater then 1 can drill down and extract the Production and NonProduction information of the users reporting under him but the condition is that the extracted report is of RoleID 1 only. 
For example, A Manager RoleID is 4 ,so firstly he drill down and find all the users reporting to him (This info is in ImmediateSupervisor column on UserInfo table)i.e RoleID 3 or RoleID 4, then again we drill down to these Users and extract information who are reporting to them and continue until we drill down up to ROleID 1 and once we drill down to that level, we extract respective users Production and NonProduction details and display in the Report.

Below is the table structure query in Create Table format;

**Production Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Production]
(
    [ProductionTimeEntryID]  [int] IDENTITY(100, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CalendarDate]           [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserID]                 [int] NOT NULL,
    [NatureOfWorkID]         [int] NOT NULL,
    [RegionProjectID]        [int] NOT NULL,
    [CountyID]               [int] NOT NULL,
    [WorkTypeID]             [int] NOT NULL,
    [TaskID]                 [int] NOT NULL,
    [VolumeProcessed]        [int] NOT NULL,
    [NosOfError]             [int] NULL,
    [NosOfVolumeAudited]     [int] NULL,
    [TimeSpent]              [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Comment]                [varchar](250) NULL,
    [IsTaskCompleted]        [int] NOT NULL,
    [isCurrentDayTask]       [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SupervisorECode]        [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Production] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ProductionTimeEntryID] ASC)
    WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Production_County] FOREIGN KEY([CountyID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[County] ([CountyID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Production_County]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Production_NatureOfWork] FOREIGN KEY([NatureOfWorkID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[NatureOfWork] ([NatureOfWorkID])
    ON 
UPDATE CASCADE
       ON

DELETE CASCADE
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Production_NatureOfWork]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Production_RegionAndProjectInfo] FOREIGN KEY([RegionProjectID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[RegionAndProjectInfo] ([RegionProjectID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production] CHECK CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Production_RegionAndProjectInfo]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Production_Task] FOREIGN KEY([TaskID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Task] ([TaskID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Production_Task]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Production_USERINFO] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[USERINFO] ([UserID])
    ON 
UPDATE CASCADE
       ON

DELETE CASCADE
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Production_USERINFO]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Production_WorkType] FOREIGN KEY([WorkTypeID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[WorkType] ([WorkTypeID])
    ON 
UPDATE CASCADE
       ON

DELETE CASCADE
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Production_WorkType]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production] ADD  DEFAULT((0)) FOR [IsTaskCompleted]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Production] ADD  DEFAULT((0)) FOR [isCurrentDayTask]
    GO
```

**UserInfo Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USERINFO](
[UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserECode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
[CCCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CCName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Password] [varchar](50) NULL,
[IsFlagEnabled] [bit] NULL,
[IsFirstTimeUserLoggedIn] [bit] NULL,
[EmailAddress] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[Designation] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ShiftStartTime] [varchar](8) NULL,
[ShiftEndTime] [varchar](8) NULL,
[WeekendShiftStartTime] [varchar](8) NULL,
[WeekendShiftEndTime] [varchar](8) NULL,
[RoleID] [int] NULL,
[ShiftEndFlagStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
[ShiftStartTimeWithTimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
[ShiftEndTimeWithTimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
[LoggedInDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[FirstLoggedInOnthedayflag] [int] NOT NULL,
[ImmediateSupervisor] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_USER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[USERINFO] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [RoleID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[USERINFO] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [ShiftEndFlagStatus]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[USERINFO] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [FirstLoggedInOnthedayflag]
GO
```

How to make such query or type of query to incorporate same in my application?

Comment: post some data and expected result, looks like recursive CTE can be used here

Comment: I had tried with sub query but not getting proper result. I want to make this query dynamic so that for any roleid , it drill down to its minimum level and gives the result. I am facing issue because so many user can reports to a Supervisor and then looping all those users to one more level down and so on. Not getting proper logic to achieve this. Any how sharing the query which i had developed so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a table with a tree structure, the standard way to extract this is to use a recursive cte, something like this:

```
;with UserTree as
(
    select UserECode, UserID
      from USERINFO
     where UserID = <the managers user-id>
    union all
    select UserECode, UserID
      from UserTree parent
           inner join USERINFO child
                   on child.ImmediateSupervisor = parent.UserECode
)
select * --change this to the specific columns that you need
  from UserTree ut
       inner join Production p
               on p.UserID = ut.UserID
 where RoleId = 1
```

Please note that I haven't managed to test this code, but I'm sure you can fix any minor issues yourself.

[More information about recursive cte:s.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

I also couldn't help but notice a couple of potential issues with your tree datastructure: ImmediateSupervisor appears to reference UserECode, and I can see two problems in the table structure that you have posted:

1. No foreign key from ImmediateSupervisor to UserECode. This could result in users that have non-existing supervisors.
2. UserECode is not unique. This could result in multiple users with the same code, which means multiple supervisors per user, and that will really screw up the recursive cte query.

I don't have the whole picture here, but with what I have I would change the ImmediateSupervisor-column to refer to the PK UserId instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot and now i am able to extract the records as per the hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

```
with
ProductionCTE(CalendarDate,RoleID,UserID,UserECode,UserName,ImmediateSupervisor,NatureOfWorkName,RegionProjectName,CountyName,WorkTypeName,TaskName,VolumneProcessed,TimeSpent,Comment)
as
(
select P.CalendarDate,U.RoleID,U.UserID,U.UserECode,U.UserName,U.ImmediateSupervisor,N.NatureofWorkName,
R.RegionProjectName,C.Countyname,W.WorktypeName,T.TaskName,P.VolumeProcessed,P.Timespent,P.Comment
from production P inner join NatureOfWork N
on N.NatureofWorkID=P.natureofworkid
inner join dbo.RegionAndProjectInfo R
on R.RegionProjectID=P.RegionProjectID
inner join county C
on C.countyid=P.countyid
inner join worktype W
on W.Worktypeid=P.worktypeID
inner join task T
on T.taskid=P.TaskID
inner join UserInfo U
on U.Userid=P.userid
where P.userid=952

    union all

        select P.CalendarDate,U.RoleID,U.UserID,U.UserECode,U.UserName,U.ImmediateSupervisor,N.NatureofWorkName,
        R.RegionProjectName,C.Countyname,W.WorktypeName,T.TaskName,P.VolumeProcessed,P.Timespent,P.Comment
        from production P inner join NatureOfWork N
        on N.NatureofWorkID=P.natureofworkid
        inner join dbo.RegionAndProjectInfo R
        on R.RegionProjectID=P.RegionProjectID
        inner join county C
        on C.countyid=P.countyid
        inner join worktype W
        on W.Worktypeid=P.worktypeID
        inner join task T
        on T.taskid=P.TaskID
        inner join UserInfo U
        on U.Userid=P.userid
        inner join ProductionCTE
        on U.ImmediateSupervisor=ProductionCTE.UserECode
)
select distinct CalendarDate,RoleID,UserID,UserECode,UserName,ImmediateSupervisor,NatureOfWorkName,RegionProjectName,CountyName,WorkTypeName,TaskName,VolumneProcessed,TimeSpent,Comment from ProductionCTE order by UserECode
```

Implementing Recursive CTE fixed the issue and now ia m able to extract the records as per hierarchy.